# XAML datasource

Tags: c#, wpf, datasource

HI:is any difference on these statements (performance or any other issues)
are they both allright?
having a datagrid datasource the PhoneNumbers is a collection
DataSource="datasource.PhoneNumbers"
or 
DataSource="{Binding Path=PhoneNumbers}"

thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

The first actually set the value of DataSource. The second *Binds* the value, which works like a reference relation.

Comment: what about if the collection is observable collection on the first case. will this behave as the one bound